# Knockout options/value bindings javascript after applyBindings does not execute

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I finally got bindings for the options and value to work on my dropdown component.  What I have now works except that all javascript after the applyBinding for the value is not executed.  This is not a problem when I only have one dropdown on the page at a time.

However, most of the time, I need to use more than one.  When I step through the script on such a page, it executes the applyBinding for the first dropdown and stops.  No further script runs, and only the first dropdown works.

Why is this?  More importantly, how do I fix it?

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
$(function () {      
  var $thisdd = $("#@ddname");  //the JQuery selector for my dropdown       
  var dropdownItems = getDropdownItemsFromDl("@ddname");       
  var newitem = ko.observable({ cname: ddcname, cvalue: ko.observable($thisdd.val()), cpublishtopic: "" });      
  classificationsViewModel.push(newitem());       
  var viewModel =     
    {         
      dditems : dropdownItems      
    };    
  $("#@ddname").attr("data-bind", "value: classificationsViewModel()[" + classificationsViewModel.indexOf(newitem()) + "].cvalue, options: dditems, optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'key'");   
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
  ko.applyBindings(classificationsViewModel()[classificationsViewModel.indexOf((newitem())].cvalue); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ko.applyBindings`, Knockout will apply the model to the entire document.
This is great if you have one model for the entire page.

It seems you want one model per dropdown. See the optional parameter on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#activating_knockout

You can then bind to each dropdown a separate model via something like `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#@ddname')[0]);`

I don't understand what this blurb is trying to do:

```
value: classificationsViewModel()[" + classificationsViewModel.indexOf(newitem()) + "].cvalue
```

It seems you're trying to use two different models to control the dropdown. I am fairly certain that won't end well. Try using one model <strike>to rule them all</strike> to handle all the dropdowns. I think you'll find it much easier to maintain and logic about.